# Improving Performance in Edge Animate

Tags: animation, adobe-edge-animate

I have a simple animation built in Adobe Edge Animate. It works great on Desktops with decent speed but it is slow to load and jerky on any other computers and mobile devices.

Are there any tips to improving performance with Adobe Edge Animate across devices for a quicker loading, smoother experience?

Here is what I have done thus far:

- Trim PNGs of all extra transparency
- Do not save any meta data with PNGs
- Code on the website is as small as possible at this point.

[Here is a link](http://www.coloradonorml.org/dev/edge.html) to the animation on a webpage.

***IMPORTANT NOTE!*** This animation is on a website for an organization that fights for the legalization of marijuana. There are marijuana leafs and references to marijuana on this page. This may not be safe for some work environments.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but...are you SURE you need that animation? Animated splash pages are quite dated.

Answer (score 1):

> **Optimize content for the web**
>
> 1. Select **File > Publish Settings**.
> 2. In the **Publish Settings** dialog box, make sure that Web is selected as the publish target.
> 3. Note or change the target directory.
> 4. Set the Frameworks Via CDN preference. 
>     Select this option to download the composition's associated jQuery assets from a content
>      delivery network (CDN). Leave the option deselected to package the
>      assets with the composition.
> 5. Set the **Publish Content** As `Static HTML` preference.  
>    Select this option to generate HTML markup instead of
>      injecting Edge Animate content into the document through JavaScript.
>      This option improves SEO-friendliness and accessibility on some
>      platforms.
> 6. Click **Save** to save the publish settings, or click **Publish**.

[Adobe Help Forum](http://helpx.adobe.com/edge-animate/using/publish-your-content.html#id_62161)